# What does a period mean in the declaration of a method?

Tags: java

In Java, What does a period mean in the declaration of a method?

For example:

```
public Swipe.SwipeResult swipeCard(String strCardNumber)
```

Can I get some more explanation of what is going on under the hood here?

Comment: Inner class/interface/enum reference.

Comment: It is part of the identifier of SwipeResult.

Either SwipeResult is an inner class in Swipe or your current class explicitly implements the method SwipeResult from an interface called Swipe.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `SwipeResult` class is declared inside the declaration of `Swipe` class, which makes it a nested class.